# Playing quicktime files with pause points via Keynote (forward and backward)

Tags: iphone, uikit, quicktime

I have a quicktime file (.mov) generated by Keynote.  When played in quicktime, it pauses itself at dozens of pre-defined points waiting for user input.  It is basically a slide show with transitions pre-rendered to video.

I want to wrap this in an iPhone app, but see no methods on an MPMoviePlayerController to do anything other than play, which does not pause at the pause points.

Also, I want to be able to play backwards to a prior stop point if the user taps elsewhere on the phone.

Is there a better library for this than MPMoviePlayerController or (deprecated?) UIMoviePlayerController?  Or am I overlooking methods that would allow this?

Comment: Hi Sam, i have the exact same problem and i wonder if you found a working solution to it. 

Best regards,

zhengtonic

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what you're trying to do, this is actually a fairly complex task.  What you're really asking for is the ability to hook up an arbitrary movie playing UI tied to unique gestures, based on the specifics of your movie.  I don't think either of the classes in question is going to get you there.

The easiest solution here might be content-based: generate one quicktime movie per "group" of Keynote slides, where each group ends at a pause point, and then it should be pretty easy to interpret gestures to either advance to the next movie (or load it automatically when you reach the end of the last one), or return to the start of the currently playing movie.